# A part of page stays in memory when you go back. How can I free resources from that old instance of page?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm developing an app on Universal Windows Platform. I've noticed that after a few minutes of navigating between pages, my app crashes on low memory devices.

I've tried using Diagnostic tools of VS2015, and here's what I found:

Each time I go from `SectionPage` to `ItemPage` and then go back to `SectionPage`, some small (~10 MB) object of that `ItemPage` remains in the memory.

This is the first time I went from `SectionPage` to `ItemPage`:

[image]

*(There's one instance of `ItemPage`)*

Then I went back to `SectionPage` and then opened that same `ItemPage`:

[image]

*(Now there's two instances of `ItemPage` in memory)*

Then I repeated it again:

[image]

... And the sixth time:

[image]

As you can see, those old instances of `ItemPage` are still in memory.

It seems that this is slowly increasing memory usage of my app, and after a while, it causes the app to crash.

So my question is, how can I release the memory related to that old `ItemPage` objects?

Comment: Typically this sort of thing is due to an event handler that wasn't disconnected, so the old object gets held in memory. Survey all the event registrations in your ItemPage and see if you can deregister them when you navigate away from it.

Comment: To continue on what Chris said, or use some form of Weak Event Handler.

Comment: @ChrisTavares Hmm, interesting. I've just removed all custom event handlers on ItemPage to confirm, and yeah that's the problem. So, do I have to *manually* remove *all* custom event handlers? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've never heard about that before, but it sounds like an interesting thing. I'll google it.